# How to trigger apt-cacher-ng's cache update on server side?

Tags: apt, package-management, apt-cacher-ng

I am running successfully `apt-cacher-ng` on a server and using it as an apt proxy for 20+ devices/vms which use various distributions, and ppas (I have no control on the client side except for the fact that they are asked to use the cache)

I'm looking for a way to trigger, on server side, when I know that network usage is minimal, an update of `apt-cacher-ng`'s cache. In other words I want to retrieve, on server-side, the latest version of all packages for all dists and proxified ppas that are being used by the proxy's clients. The goal being to make sure that when clients triger an upgrade, the odds are as high as possible that the cache has already been updated (and packages are thus available for immediate download).

I imagine having a cron job that triggers a script which scans `apt-cacher-ng`'s cache, retrieves information about the cache, dists, ppas, packages, and requests a download of the latest version of all packages (without installing them locally)

Unfortunately, I don't know where to start to "make it real", and could'nt find a tool/script which does this (maybe it's a dumb idea that's why nodody achieved it yet).

What would be the best way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [partial mirroring](https://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/%7Ebloch/acng/html/howtos.html#mirroring) feature in `apt-cacher-ng`.

> It is possible to create a partial local mirror of a remote package
> repository. The method to do this is usually known as pre-caching.
> ...
> The CGI URL generated by the browser can be called with other clients
> to repeat this job, for example in a daily executed script.

However, I would argue the best solution is for the **clients** to configure the `APT::Periodic` settings.

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "1";
```

Advantages to this approach

- only packages needed will be downloaded and cached.
- when the client goes to upgrade all the packages will already be downloaded to the client.
- there is a built-in random sleep to the `apt` periodic scripts that protects the proxy against a flood of requests.  This also helps ensure only the first client is impacted if a file is not in the cache.

If you are able to request that the clients use the proxy then I would hope you could also request the clients configure the periodic settings.

All the `APT::Periodic` options are described in [the apt.systemd.daily script](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/blob/c6f016200291e7e719f15de4f9a6ad9596c5110b/debian/apt.systemd.daily#L53).

```
#  APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "0";
#  - Do "apt-get update" automatically every n-days (0=disable)
#    
#  APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "0";
#  - Do "apt-get upgrade --download-only" every n-days (0=disable)
```